# Get random sentences from Free Dictionary API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to grab random sentences from Free Dictionary API and add them based on time on a web page.

The basic idea is like this:

```js
var randomSentence = get a randomSentence from api.dictionaryapi.dev/api;

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".random-sentence").append(randomSentence);
  }, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="random-sentence"></div>
```

Here is some information about the API:
https://github.com/meetDeveloper/freeDictionaryAPI

How can I get sentences randomly? Would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm wrong but I don't see a way to get sentences from freeDictionaryAPI unless it's in the returned JSON of whatever word you get the definition of.

So the first method you could take that I thought of from the top of my head is just to get a random English word and use that in the API, and return the word's example sentence.

Comment: I think the idea with the random word is okay. It's kind of the same logic, just bundled. Do you know how to code that?

Comment: @Anna_B If you're fine using Node.js then https://github.com/apostrophecms/random-words

Comment: It looks like a pretty small library of words